# Determining relationship between rows using subqueries in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to complete the following task in a single query.
Basically, given a user's ID, I want to return the user profiles of all users he is friends with.
If anything is unclear, I'll be happy to go into more detail. Thanks!

> **table 'users':**
>
> ```
>  user_id  |  col1  |  col2   |  etc
> -----------------------------------------
>  a        |  ***   | ***     |  ***
> -----------------------------------------
>  b        |  ***   | ***     |  ***
> ```
>
> **table 'users_friends'**
>
> ```
>  user_id  |  friend_user_id  |  status
> -----------------------------------------
>  a        |  b               |  1
> -----------------------------------------
>  b        |  a               |  1
> ```

given a value of **a**, find rows in table **users_friends** where

```
user_id = a
status = 1
```

using the resulting rows of that query, find rows in table **users_friends** where

```
user_id = b          (column `user_friend_id` from resulting rows) 
user_friend_id = a   (column `user_id` from resulting rows) 
status = 1
```

if any rows are returned, select rows from table 'users' where

```
user_id = b          (column `user_id` from resulting row)
```

This is a really rough one I came up with. I think it does what I'm looking for, but I'm sure there are better ways to go about it.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN 
    (SELECT user_id FROM users_friends WHERE friend_user_id IN
              (SELECT user_id FROM users_friends WHERE user_id = 'someuserid' AND status = 1 ) AND status = 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.*
from
    users u
    inner join
    users_friends f on u.user_id = f.friend_user_id
where
    f.status = 1
    and f.friend_user_id = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no duplicates in friends table:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.col1, u.col2
JOIN users_friends AS f1 ON u.user_id=f1.user_id
JOIN users_friends AS f2 ON f1.user_id=f2.friend_id AND f1.friend_id=f2.user_id
WHERE f1.status=1 AND f2.status=1 AND f2.user_id='a'
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a720e/1)

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.col1
FROM users_friends AS f
JOIN users AS u
    ON f.friend_user_id = u.user_id
WHERE f.user_id = 'a'
AND f.status = 1
```